# How to animate window minimizing with Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside6, pyqt6

I have this code:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint) 
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)


        # CustomBar + Main Widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.custom_bar = CustomBar(self)
        self.custom_bar.minimize_btn.clicked.connect(self.minimize_animation)
        self.main_widget = MainWidget()

        # Animation
        self._window_opacity = self.windowOpacity()
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"window_opacity", self)
        self.animation.setDuration(200)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Type.BezierSpline)
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.minimize_window)

        # adding widgets
        layout.addWidget(self.custom_bar)
        layout.addWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    @Property(float)
    def window_opacity(self):
        return self._window_opacity

    @window_opacity.setter
    def window_opacity(self, val):
        self._window_opacity = val
        self.setWindowOpacity(self._window_opacity)

    def eventFilter(self, s, e: QEvent) -> bool:
        if s is not self:
            return False
        if e.type() is e.Type.WindowStateChange:
            # run window openning animation
            if e.oldState() in [Qt.WindowState.WindowMinimized, Qt.WindowState.WindowMinimized|Qt.WindowState.WindowMaximized]:
                self.animation.pause()
                self.animation.setDirection(QPropertyAnimation.Direction.Backward)
                self.animation.start()
            return True
        return False

    def minimize_animation(self):
        self.animation.pause()
        self.animation.setDirection(QPropertyAnimation.Direction.Forward)
        self.animation.start()

    def minimize_window(self, *args):
        if self.window().windowOpacity() == 0:
            self.window().showMinimized()
```

The window minimization animation works, but only if I click the appropriate button in the `CustomBar`.
I solved the problem with the animation of returning the window to normal state by using `EventFilter` (the window returns not by clicking on my button, but by clicking on the application icon in the *Windows* dockbar).
However, if I minimize the window by clicking not on my button, but on the icon in the *Windows* dockbar, there will be no animation, the window will just disappear.

I tried to do it the same way through `EventFilter`, like when minimizing, first return the window to normal state and then play the animation, but because of `setWindowState` there was a conflict, and started animation of window opening and a bunch of other bugs.

Is it possible to add animation of window minimization when clicking on the icon in the dockbar?

Comment: I have not enough experience on Windows, but don't think there is a *clean* and reliable way to do this: when the icon is clicked on the taskbar the OS *commands* the window to hide, and you're able to temporarily restore the previous state, there will probably be flickering in some configurations. On another note, installing the event filter on `self` is completely pointless, as that's not the purpose event filters. Just override `event()`.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot for what you said about `EventFilter`, have read more about it.